# Connect meteor Dapp to ethereum testnet

Tags: testnets, dapps, meteor

I'm trying to build a Dapp using Meteor and Ethereum, but I'm having trouble connecting Meteor to Ethereum testnet. How can I do that? and is it possible to do without using a client such as metamask?

Comment: Hi there. I think the question I've linked to should answer your questions (see the accepted answer). For this part: _"and is it possible to do without using a client such as metamask?"_ You'll need to either use Metamask, or run your own client on the testnet.

Comment: I still do not know how to link meteor to an ethereum smart contract?

Comment: Are you following a particular tutorial?

Comment: No I'm not, if you know of a good tutorial, please share it :)